# How to extract all strings prefixed and suffixed with a char from log file using nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm newbie to `Nodejs`, and was wondering if there is a nodejs library that I could use to extract every occurrence of string that is prefixed with `^` and suffixed with `$` i.e. `^abcde&`. Each occurrence needs to be stored into an `Array` and then print those into console.

Here is how the content of `my.log` file looks like:

```
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [10/Sep/2015:11:34:54:455 +0100] ^somerandomstring1$ 200
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [10/Sep/2015:11:34:55:455 +0100] ^somerandomstring2$ 404
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [10/Sep/2015:11:34:56:455 +0100] ^somerandomstring3$ 500
```

Ideally, the each of those strings needs to be stored into an array and then I want to iterate over them and print them onto console like :

`console:`

`>>somerandomstring1`
`>>somerandomstring1`
`>>somerandomstring1`

Answer (score 1):

I haven't use it, but I suppose [regex module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/regex) will solve your problem.

But, in fact a module isn't necessary. JavaScript's native functions may be enough.

There is a excellent guide about JavaScript regex in the [Mozilla Developer Network's site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

But a module can be a option.

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't need a module for that. A simple function with regex will do the trick.

```
function extract(str) {
  var re = /\^([^$]*)\$/g;
  var ret = [];
  do {
    m = re.exec(str);
    if (m) {
      ret.push(m[1]);
    }
  } while (m);
  return ret;
}
```

This function will give you an array with just the string between the ^...$; it's then trivial to iterate over it and prefix whatever you want (such as ">>").